# Mongo DB issue with findOne query

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am maintaining a rooms table, where it consists of records associated with the conversations. I want to get the room id between two users so using `findOne` query but it's bringing other records and not satisfying my need. 
Suggest me where the query has gone wrong.

If I give the query:
`rooms.findOne({ "userId" :"800", "userId" :"600"});` 
I am expectng conversation id of `fsny11z742kpgb9` but it's giving `6puebew70kke29`.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("571c5724db62826826d28d08"),
    "conversationId": "6puebew70kke29",
    "userId": "600",
    "firstName": "Test",
    "profileImagePath": "",
    "created": ISODate("2016-04-24T05:18:28.753Z"),
    "__v": 0
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId("571c5724db62826826d28d09"),
    "conversationId": "6puebew70kke29",
    "userId": "900",
    "firstName": "User",
    "profileImagePath": "",
    "created": ISODate("2016-04-24T05:18:28.754Z"),
    "__v": 0
}

{
    "_id": ObjectId("571c574edb62826826d28d0b"),
    "conversationId": "fsny11z742kpgb9",
    "userId": "600",
    "firstName": "FitTest",
    "profileImagePath": "",
    "created": ISODate("2016-04-24T05:19:10.192Z"),
    "__v": 0
}

{
    "_id": ObjectId("571c574edb62826826d28d0c"),
    "conversationId": "fsny11z742kpgb9",
    "userId": "800",
    "firstName": "Dev",
    "profileImagePath": "",
    "created": ISODate("2016-04-24T05:19:10.193Z"),
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: In the query, why do you write UserID twice?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any 'type' field in your data. So I wonder why a query with 'type': 'PRIVATE' returns something.

Comment: I want the convesationID which relates both the user tats why gave userId twice

Comment: @MathieuLordon: Assume that I have a grouptype private or group is that anyway to add another field like groupType : 'PRIVATE' like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use aggregation to do so.

```js
rooms.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: '$conversationId', users: { $push: '$userId' } } },
  { $match: { users: { $all: ['800', '600'] }, groupType: 'PRIVATE' } },
])
```

Comment: This. I believe you should aggregate so that both UserId's match.

Comment: @MathieuLordon: Assume that I have a grouptype private or group is that anyway to add another field like groupType : 'PRIVATE' like that?

Comment: I edited my post to match only private conversations. For better performance, you could also filter by groupType BEFORE the $group stage (with an index on groupType of course).

Comment: What your data look like with groupType?

Comment: actually no data are coming if I add the grouptype as you have said

Comment: If there is no conversation between user 600 and user 800 with the groupType set to 'PRIVATE' in your data, it's normal.

Answer (score 1):

The findOne() operation returns the first document according to the natural order which reflects the order of documents on the disk, see [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/).

Second, the query document you provide as parameter to the `findOne()` operation contains two values for `userId`, this is not the same as the [$in operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/). The latter one overrides the first one.

As Mathieu suggested, a proper lookup would be to use an aggregation pipeline with two steps:

```
rooms.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: '$conversationId', users: { $push: '$userId' } } },
  { $match: { users: { $all: ['800', '600'] }, groupType: 'PRIVATE' } },
])
```

1. create list with id matching the conversation id and a field of type array containing all the userIds ($group stage)
2. filter out all entries, where the user-array contains the ids of the both users your are looking for. ($match stage)

Bear in mind, that this will return *all* conversations of both users.